# How to catch user checking out time?

Tags: magento-1.9, time

I am trying to display a message for the user once they begin checking out a product past a certain time (10AM).

How would I go about doing this? Is this even possible? I'm just not sure how to catch the time from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the Javascript [Date](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp) object. It uses the browser (device) time.

Something like the following would work

```
<div id="divWithWarningTextId" style="display:none;">It's past 10!</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var time = new Date();
if (time.getHours() >= 22) {
  document.getElementById('divWithWarningTextId').style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Sometimes stuff can be simple ;)